# How to get User-Agent of Outlook add-in and use it for controlling access to EWS in Exchange

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm a developer of one of Outlook add-ins.

We got a support request from one of our users about broken functionality related to attachments.

To get email attachments from our server we call EWS Managed API using `ewsUrl` and `ewsToken` passed from the client-side. Turns out, that Exchange admins can disable EWS and we were able to reproduce this.

We found this article which says that there's a way to enable EWS for specific apps:

[Control access to EWS in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-control-access-to-ews-in-exchange)

Admins of user's Exchange don't want to enable EWS for all users, so they want to enable it only for our app using this instruction:
[image: image.png]
This says that they can use a User-Agent string. So my question is **how to get User-Agent for our Outlook add-in**? Is this user agent string is fixed for each individual app or is it something we can set on our server in `User-Agent` header when we send requests to EWS?

Comment: To clarify, it's your server making the EWS request, so that's the user agent you want to set, so that the admin can allow that user agent right? This is instead of getting/setting the user-agent for your add-in. Since you are using EWS managed API, have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservicebase.useragent?view=exchange-ews-api?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure it's EWS Managed API. We send POST request to Exchange server as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item#use-ews-to-get-the-attachments
I did a test, I whitelisted add-in as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-control-access-to-ews-in-exchange with the command `Set-OrganizationConfig -EwsApplicationAccessPolicy:EnforceAllowList -EwsAllowList:"test/*"` and set `User-Agent` header to be `test/123`. And access is still not allowed.

Comment: What you did looks right. Could you capture the request + response of your POST request to make sure the user agent and you are seeing a 403 (the expected error for being disallowed). Another thing to look at is whether EWS is blocked in client access rules https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-clientaccessrule?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Thank you @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT
Turns out it should take a few hours for allowing access for specific User-Agent to be applied to EWS. I confirmed that my solution worked. I let our customer know about this and waiting for their response. If this won't help, we'll try you second suggestion.

Comment: got it. I just moved part of the comment to the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are posting the EWS request from your backend, you can set the user-agent header in the requests you send to EWS.